# How can I see Puppet-managed file contents that would be created in --noop mode for nonexistent files?

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

**Context:**

If there's a Puppet managed file on my system, and Puppet wants to change the contents, it will usually tell me the differences that it would have made if not for `--noop`.

However, if that file doesn't exist, `--noop` output just tells me `should be file`.

**Question:**

Is there some way to configure `--noop` mode (or other verbosity/debugging settings) to see what contents it would put into that file, if it doesn't already exist?

**What I've Tried:**

If I run Puppet (agent or apply) in `--noop` mode, with `--debug` and `--verbose`, I get a lot of information, but not the info I want. Perhaps there's some way using the generated/cached catalog?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any puppet option that would give you what you're looking for but perhaps you could create an empty file and then run puppet with --noop

On Unix you can run:

```
touch /path/to/file
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the main reason I use --noop is before significant Puppet runs on production servers. I'm loath to touch files whose existence might act as a flag for running software.

Comment: Ouch, I see. Do you have a mirror dev/staging environment that could help? Sorry I'm not aware of anything that could help atm :(

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'm trying something with multiple puppetmasters and agents on the production environment, with one agent only running noops and emailing the results. Which would be fine, if it weren't for some very poor decisions that resulted in our custom facts changing system state :( :(

Comment: Clever suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to "debug" templates. You might want to take a look at [language puppet](http://lpuppet.banquise.net). You can use the provided `puppetresources` binary that way :

> puppetresources -p /path/to/puppet/root -o node.name.domain -n /path/to/created/file -c

This will compile the catalog for the given node, filter for a resource named with the proper path (`-n` flag), and print its content on stdout (`-c` flag).

Comment: Not quite what I'm after; I can view the compiled catalog fine, but when that catalog is applied to a host that doesn't have the file, it would be useful to see its contents as part of the `noop` run (though I could deal with having to run a separate command).